# Module not found: Can't resolve '@coreui/dist/css/coreui.min.css' for CoreUI with React

Tags: reactjs, core-ui

Trying to configure CoreUI with my React App but I'm receiving an error:

I followed the instructions at: https://coreui.io/react/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction  and added:

```
import '@coreui/dist/css/coreui.min.css';
```

to the top of my .js file but I'm getting an error:

*Module not found: Can't resolve '@coreui/dist/css/coreui.min.css'*

Comment: reinstall the pkg

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the package install,use this command:

```
npm install @coreui/coreui
```

After this,it should work!

Answer (score 1):

As Brandon correctly pointed out, the documentation is currently incorrect.

`import '@coreui/coreui/dist/css/coreui.min.css';`

When I imported it this way, all of my styles instantly turned my page from ugly to beautiful.

Answer (score -1):

It's installed. However, the path is incorrect in the instructions. To fix, it should be @coreui/coreui/dist.....

Comment: In the documentation,they said : import '@coreui/dist/css/coreui.min.css'